# jquery set variable to true and get if var is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating form fields, when all form fields are filled out correctly I want to enable the submit button. my validating is working, but not setting a variable to be true and checking that variable. for example..

```
if(password != confirm_password) {
$("#password_mismatch").css("display", "inline");
} else {
$("#password_mismatch").css("display", "none");
var password_match_valid = true;
return false;
}
```

this function checks that everything is validated and enables the button

```
function validate(){
if ($('#name').val().length   >   0   &&
    password_match_valid == true) {
    $('#signup_btn').prop("disabled", false);
}
else {
    $('#signup_btn').prop("disabled", true);
}
}
```

the bit that is causing problems is

```
var password_match_valid = true;
```

and

```
password_match_valid == true
```

Comment: looks like the variable `password_match_valid` is in a local scope...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets a local variable :

```
var password_match_valid = true;
```

This variable isn't visible from outside the function in which it's declared, especially it's not visible from the `validate` function.

A solution is to make it global, by adding

```
var password_match_valid;
```

in the global scope and removing the `var` keyword you currently have.

But it's not clear why the test isn't done in the `validate` function directly so there might be a cleaner solution, depending on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `password_match_valid` needs to be global. For that declare it outside any function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var password_match_valid = true;
```

This var lives only in your `else` statement. Into `validate()` function you don't have visibility on `password_match_valid`. Try with a global var.